# jQuery Plugin: Add method with .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following code in a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.myForm = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var myForm = new MyForm(this);

        $.data(myForm, 'myForm');
    });
};
```

I thought that doing this, would allow me to then access the inner functions of `myForm`, such as `getForm`

```
var MyForm = function() {
   //...
   function getForm() {
       return 'Hi';
   }
}
```

But when I try to access `myForm` from outside the plugin, I get `undefined`:

```
$('#test').myForm();
$('#test').data('myForm')
> undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set your `data` like this:-

```
$(this).data('myForm', myForm);
```

Comment: That worked. Had to assign `$('#test').myForm()` and that did the trick.

Comment: @PepperedLemons [`$.data(this, 'myForm', myForm);`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) should also work. – The issue with `$.data(myForm, 'myForm')` is that the element isn't being provided to attach `myForm` to.